# What is the link to somebody's Gmail calendar

Tags: gmail, google-calendar

I got an gmail account. Address of my account is: `me@gmail.com` and somebody's email address is : `him@gmail.com`.  `him@gmail.com` gave `me@gmail.com` account rights to view and modify his calendar.

In my web appplication I try to create link which will lead to `him@gmail.com` calendar view only. Although this is not coding question.

I would like to know if it is possible and how would link to `him@gmail.com` calendar would look like.

Answer (score 0):

Your friend is going to need to send you the special link so that you can access the calendar; you can't simply derive it from someone's account name.

Near the bottom of the calendar settings page on the "Calendar details" tab are buttons to get the links. It looks like this:

[image: calendar links]

Depending on what you need you'll want the data from the XML, ICAL or HTML buttons.

Here's what an HTML link looks like:

[image: HTML link to a calendar]

The XML button provide an RSS feed, while the iCal button will point to an `.ics` file.

**However**, in order to access the calendar, you'll still need to log in to Google with your credentials once you click the link. If your web app can do that, then you're in good shape. If not, well, that's beyond the scope of this site.